# How to skip AutoHotKey reaction and send "normal" key

Tags: autohotkey

How can I "skip" the script bound to the key and perform a "normal" press? For example, if a script is installed on the A key with a condition check that has not been met and just the A button should go? If i just do send {a}, i have endless script call.

Exemple:

```
a::
if bool_expression
{
   ...
}
else
{
  send {a}                  ; Not work - endless script call. How to disable it and send simple "a" key.
}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your hotkey context sensitive, using the [**#If directive**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_If.htm). Then you don't need the else statement to perform a normal press:

```
#If bool_expression

    $a::
        do something
    return

#If ; turn off context sensitivity
```