# Dynamic default key action

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a script that will trigger key numbers from 1 to 3

I was trying:

```
KeyNum := 1
1:: {   
    global KeyNum 
    Send KeyNum 

    KeyNum := KeyNum + 1
    
    if (KeyNum > 3) {
        KeyNum := 1
    }
}
```

but the output was `232323`, so I changed it to:

```
KeyNum := 1
~1:: {      
    global KeyNum 
    Send KeyNum 

    KeyNum := KeyNum + 1
    
    if (KeyNum > 3) {
        KeyNum := 1
    }
}
```

but then I got `111213111213`

How can I prevent default action in the `~1::` version?

**or**

How can I call the default key action in the `1::` version?

I found [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77027232/how-to-skip-autohotkey-reaction-and-send-normal-key) but I don't know is it possible to implement it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `$`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar)</sup> prefix.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey 2

$1::
{
    static num := 1
    SendInput(num++)
    if (num > 3)
        num := 1
}
```